# Text next to a div that serves as a line

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS for a line with a circle at the beginning.

This circle serves as an information for an image - it points at it - hence I need some text at the end of the line. Roughly like this:

---------- Text

How do I implement this?

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #D3072A;
  border: solid 1px #D3072A;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9px;
  left: -1px;
}

.markers {
  top: 10%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #D3072A;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="markers">
   <div class="circle">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: put the text right after first div tag starts (before start of circle div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve that by using `:after` selector:

**Example:**

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #D3072A;
  border: solid 1px #D3072A;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9px;
  left: -1px;
}

.markers {
  top: 10%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #D3072A;
  position: absolute;
}
.markers::after {
  width:100%;
  content:"Text"; /*Text here*/
  position:absolute;
  right:-100%;
  top:-9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="markers">
   <div class="circle">
   </div>
</div>
```

I hope this works.